# MySQL group by with rollup, coalesce/ifnull, and date functions

Tags: mysql, date, coalesce, rollup

I have run into an issue with MySQL's ROLLUP and dealing with the resulting NULLs.  The IFNULL/COALESCE functions work well with plain columns, but seem to break down when used with date functions.  Examples follow:

```
SELECT
    YEAR(date_time) AS Year,
    count(x) AS Count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP
```

returns (as expected)

```
Year Count
---- -----
2015 3
2016 2
NULL 5
```

When I query for non-date columns (varchar, for example), I can deal with the NULL values by using IFNULL or COALESCE functions to replace NULL values with strings.  However, when I apply the same logic to the above query, it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(YEAR(date_time), 'moo') AS Year,
    count(x) AS Count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP
```

or

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(YEAR(date_time), 'moo') AS 'year',
    count(x) AS Count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY year WITH ROLLUP
```

returns

```
Year Count
---- -----
2015 3
2016 2
NULL 5
```

instead of expected

```
Year Count
---- -----
2015 3
2016 2
moo  5
```

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: This question makes little sense to me, because you are not actually rolling anything up, as there is no aggregate function being used with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Only because I've pared the query down to a bear minimum to get at the heart of my question

Comment: Then you should show a representative sample.  What you gave above does not make any sense because there is no rollup.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you're nitpicking, but I've updated the question

Comment: Your question is more clear now, but @UnixOne beat me to the answer :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to target the `NULL`'s generated during the aggregate rollup calculations (as opposed to `NULL`s in your raw data), you're referring to the wrong `NULL`s. If so, this is probably what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(m.year, 'moo')
FROM
    (SELECT
        YEAR(date_time) AS 'year'
     FROM
        mytable
     GROUP BY
        year
     WITH ROLLUP) m
```

Here's the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44c01a/1).

Comment: This definitely addresses my problem.  What I don't understand is why the same query works fine with a different type of column?  (i.e. for a varchar, this works just fine: `SELECT COALESCE(category, 'moo') FROM categories GROUP BY category WITH ROLLUP;`)

Comment: The difference is not the column type, but the grouping by derived vs the raw value. In the "varchar query" in your comment above, you're grouping by `category`, not the derived value in your `SELECT`. See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/378b70/7).

Comment: I think I see what you are saying, especially in case of a NULL value in the original table, but I was referring more to the NULLs generated by ROLLUP. Also, there is more than one issue at play. Look at the 4 pairs of queries in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c794b/3).The first two pairs demonstrate that it matters whether you GROUP BY column name or an alias you created in SELECT, regardless of column type. The last two pairs demonstrate that if you need to functionally manipulate the column data inside the GROUP BY statement, COALESCE will not work (again regardless of type)